# Startup Application Show "Not Measured" Not Running At Startup

Tags: c#, startup

My application need some administrator previlage. So i made it run as administrator. In my application i am getting all user from PC. Then I am modifying startup entry of registry for some user. after that when i show task it shows "Not measured". And also not starting application at startup.

Comment: You can't have programs that run at startup that have a UAC prompt. Windows stops the program from loading.

Comment: I disabled UAC promt in windows. through "Change User Account Control Settings". But now in task manager it shows Startup Impact High. but not starting application at startup

Comment: Squarely falls in the "things you should never do" category.  If that would work, the user would see the UAC consent dialog immediately after logging in.  But having no real idea how that happened and what he gives consent to, deeply annoying to any computer user of course.  Workaround is to use *two* programs, one that doesn't require UAC to run and displays a little window with a "Run" button.  Which starts the one that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I created shortcut for to the application in startup folder. then modified my app to run normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task Scheduler to achieve this.
Create a new task with the option 'Run with highest privileges' checked and with a trigger of 'Begin the task: At startup'

This way the scheduler will run your application with administrator privileges at startup without prompting the user.